# Collect rows based on unique ID Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large time series dataset with some of the observations (each with a unique ID) having a different length. I also have a 'Section' column that counts time step or rows for each unique ID.

```
df.groupby([df['ID']]).agg({'count'})

                                  A             B                         Z
                                 count         count         ...         count   
    ID                                                        
    25782                          194           194                      194   
    25783                          198           198                      198   
    25784                          194           194                      194   
    25785                          192           192                      192   
   ...                             ...           ...          ...          ...
    25787                          192           192                      192   
    25788                          195           195                      195   
    25789                          196           196                      196   
    25790                          200           200                      200
```

say I want to create a new dataframe consisting only where the length of unique ID = 192. I.e 'Section' counts up to 192.

So far I have tried the following but for no avail. Please help.

```
mask = df.groupby('ID')(len(df['Section']) == 192)
df = df.loc[mask]
print(df)
```

AND

```
df.groupby('ID').df[df['Section'].max() == 192]
```

**edit**

Desired output

```
new_df.groupby([new_df['ID']]).agg({'count'})

                               A             B                         Z
                             count         count         ...         count   
ID                                                        
25752                          192           192                      192   
25137                          192           192                      192   
25970                          192           192                      192   
25440                          192           192                      192
```

Comment: perhaps you could include your expected output just so we have a good representation and we are not trying to guess what you need

Comment: @jpp, yes df['Section'] is numeric, and df[df['Section'] <= 192] takes the first 193 rows of all length of unique ID > 192.

Comment: @jpp, no It didn't. df.ID.nunique() == new_df.ID.nunique().

Comment: Maybe have a look at [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) to just keep the `ID` with length of 192 such as `new_df = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: len(x['Section']) == 192)` or something like that

Comment: @Ben.T Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. I would accept it as the correct answer if you can answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) after the `groupby`  to keep only the `ID` where the length of the 'Section' column is 192, such as:

```
new_df = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: len(x['Section']) == 192)
```

Then when you do `new_df.groupby('ID').agg({'count'})` you should get your expected output